# pl/sql procedure returns 3 question marks ('???') for varchar2 columns (wls 10.3.4 - weblogic 11g)

Tags: java, plsql, weblogic11g, varchar2

I got the following code that works fine on OAS10, for fetching array of custom object from sql procedure:

```
Connection conn = null;
OracleCallableStatement stmt = null;
RequestsWrapper requestsWrapper = null;
conn = getConnection(DATASOURCE);
if (conn != null) {
    stmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call packageName.procedureName(?, ?, ?)}");
    stmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "V_ARRAY_OF_CUSTOM_OBJECTS");
    stmt.setString(1, in1);
    stmt.setString(2, in2);
    stmt.execute();
    ARRAY zahtjev = (ARRAY) cs.getArray(3);
    RequestsWrapper requestsWrapper = new RequestsWrapper();
    for (Object object : (Object[]) zahtjev.getArray()) {
        if (object != null) {
              CustomObject co = new CustomObject();
              Object[] attributes = ((STRUCT) object).getAttributes();
              co.setVarcharAttribute((String) attributes[0]);
              co.setNumericAttribute(((BigDecimal) attributes[1]).intValue());
              requestsWrapper.getObjectList().add(co);
       }
    }
}
```

and I have to migrate application to WLS 10.3.4.
When I tried to execute existing code, I got an exception: cannot cast to oracle.sql.ARRAY. 
I found in WLS documentation:

> For most extensions in the Oracle Thin driver, you can use the
>   standard technique as described in Using API Extensions to JDBC
>   Interfaces.  However, the Oracle Thin driver does not provide public
>   interfaces for its extension methods in the following classes:
>
> oracle.sql.ARRAY
>   oracle.sql.STRUCT
>   oracle.sql.REF
>   oracle.sql.BLOB 
>   oracle.sql.CLOB
>
> WebLogic Server provides its own interfaces to access the extension
>   methods for those classes:
>
> weblogic.jdbc.vendor.oracle.OracleArray 
>   weblogic.jdbc.vendor.oracle.OracleStruct 
>   weblogic.jdbc.vendor.oracle.OracleRef 
>   weblogic.jdbc.vendor.oracle.OracleThinBlob 
>   weblogic.jdbc.vendor.oracle.OracleThinClob

So, I followed the instructions and I got following code

```
Connection conn = null;
OracleCallableStatement stmt = null;
RequestsWrapper requestsWrapper = null;
conn = getConnection(DATASOURCE);
if (conn != null) {
    ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("V_ARRAY_OF_CUSTOM_OBJECTS", conn);
    StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("T_CUSTOM_OBJECT", conn);
    stmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call packageName.procedureName(?, ?, ?)}");
    stmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "V_ARRAY_OF_CUSTOM_OBJECTS");
    stmt.setString(1, in1);
    stmt.setString(2, in2);
    stmt.execute();
    Array request = stmt.getArray(3);
    OracleArray requestOracleArray =  ((weblogic.jdbc.vendor.oracle.OracleArray)request).getOracleArray(); 
    Datum[] datumArray = ((weblogic.jdbc.vendor.oracle.OracleArray)request).getOracleArray();
    RequestsWrapper requestsWrapper = new RequestsWrapper();
    for (Datum object : datumArray) {
        if (object != null) {
           CustomObject co = new CustomObject();
           Object[] attributes = ((Struct) object).getAttributes();
           co.setVarcharAttribute((String) attributes[0]);
           co.setNumericAttribute(((BigDecimal) attributes[1]).intValue());
           requestsWrapper.getObjectList().add(co);
       }
    }
}
```

and numeric attribute is mapped OK, but instead of varchar2 attribute, I have '???'.
Does anyone have similar problem?

Thanks in advance.

*edit: i found on few pages info that orai18n.jar should be added to server classpath. but it doesn't work for me.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

at the end, orai18n.jar is solution. i had to include it in CLASSPATH of weblogic, so in %MY_DOMAIN%\bin folder in setDomainEnv.cmd just added

set CLASSPATH=%WL_HOME%\server\ext\jdbc\oracle\11g\orai18n.jar

and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it means you have unicode stuff in your varchar2 fields. Please consider about it.

Comment: that was first hint, that i had special characters. so, i checked fields and now varchar2 fileds are 'clean'. only characters a-z and 0-9 are inside.